# как правильно отправлять форму методом Post?

Tags: post, form

всем доброго вечера. я только начинаю изучать PHP и мой маршрутизатор на сайте устроен по принципу обыкновенного ветвления.
с методом Get меня все устраивает. Но по поводу метода Post - есть сомнения.

чтобы указать имя класса и вызываемого метода я использую в формах скрытые поля с указанием этих самых классов и методов. Работает все четко и быстро. Но правильно ли я делаю? Или есть какой-то еще способ для новичков указать эти данные при отправке формы?

Типичный заголовок моей формы:

```
<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="class" value="content">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="get">
```

затем идет сама форма, button, ну и так далее.

Comment: можете в свойстве `action` формы указывать. Получать атрибуты как get. Лучше всё же переходить на такие ссылки `content/get`

Comment: а можете ссылку кинуть где почитать про это? я плохо понимаю как задать этот вопрос в гугл. то есть каким образом прописать это в свойстве action

Comment: https://elisdn.ru/blog/114/psr7-framework-router

Comment: спасибо,  ознакомимся!